# Singularity of $f(z) = \frac{1}{e^z-1} $ at $z_0=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Obviously $f(z) = \frac{1}{e^z-1} $ has a singularity at $z_0=0$.

Now I want to know classify this singularity.

$$ \frac{1}{e^z -1} = \frac{1}{z+\frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + ...}$$

Considering [Rieman's theorem on removable singularites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity), the singularity is not removable since $$ \lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z) = \lim_{z \to 0} \, zf(z) = \lim_{z\to0} \, \frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2!} + ..} = 1 \neq 0 $$

To be a pole, there must exist $k \in \mathbb N$, $k\geq 1$ so that $ g(z) := z^k f(z) $ has a removable singularity.

Checking $g(z)$ for having a removable singularity:

$$ \lim_{z\to 0} \,\, z^{k+1} \frac{1}{z+\frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + ...} = 0 $$
which is true for $k=1$, thus $f(z)$ has a pole of order $1$.

I am asking if this is correct, since it is against my intuition that an infinite series has a pole of order $1$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: The function $e^z-1$ has a _zero_ of order $1$ at $z_0=0$. It stands to reason that it becomes a pole of order $1$ when you invert it.